# Gson, Jackson, Flaten Map/HashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jackson2

Say I have a POJO as follows -

```
public class Pojo {

    String name;
    String address;
    Map<String, String> values;

    //getter/setters 
}
```

If, I convert it to a `String` in `JSON` format using `Jackson`, as follows -

```
    Pojo pojo= new Pojo ();
    pojo.setName("My Name");
    pojo.setAddress("Yet not found");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "val1");
    map.put("key2", "val2");
    map.put("key3", "val3");

    pojo.setValues(map);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(parentPojo);
    System.out.println(str);
```

I get a `String` in `JSON` format as follows -

```
{
    "name": "My Name",
    "address": "Yet not found",
    "values": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3"
    }
}
```

Is there any way, I can make it as follows, using `Gson/Jackson`?

```
{
    "name": "ParentName",
    "address": "Yet not found",
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3"
}
```

**NOTE - I know it can be done easily, if I put everything inside a Single `Map`, But I Can NOT do that, I have some other business logic that depends on those.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jackson, annotate `getValues()` with [`@JsonAnyGetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) and `setValues()` with [`@JsonAnySetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html):

```
public class Pojo {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Map<String, String> values;

    // Getters and setters for name and address

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setValues(Map<String, String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is like very foolish, but i am very new to here